# Querying Facebook Graph API for Reels and Metrics on Video Posts

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video-capture, facebook-marketing-api

Question:
I'm working with the Facebook Graph API to retrieve video data from user accounts. Currently, when querying the `videos` edge, I get both individual videos and reels. The only distinguishing factor for reels seems to be the permalink_url containing `"/reel/"` in the response. Ex:

```
"permalink_url": "/reel/12345678987654321/"
```

However, I'm facing challenges in two areas:

Question 1:
Is there an alternative method or endpoint to specifically query for reels? I've explored the `video_reels` endpoint, but it returns zero results for accounts that I know have reel video posts.

Question 2:
For video posts identified as reels, I'm limited to a set amount of fields, and I specifically need metrics. As of now, I can only retrieve the views metric. Are there additional metrics or alternative approaches to gather more data on reels?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions to obtain comprehensive metrics for reel video posts. Thank you!